# Wordpress, add a <span> tag to all links

Tags: php, html, wordpress

When I write a blog post on my Wordpress site, I want do dynamically add a span-tag inside all the anchor tags, with a data-attribute that has the same value as the anchor tag.

**Example**

What I write in Wordpress:

```html
<p>Some text with <a href="#">a link in it</a></p>
```

What generates:

```html
<p>Some text with <a href="#"><span data-title="a link in it">a link in it</span></a>
```

How can you do this with jQuery or PHP?

Comment: I'm curious why you want to do this?

Comment: why would you need to do this? it's additional markup that achieves nothing that the `<a>` tag couldn't achieve on its own. You could just as easily add the `title` attribute to the `<a>` tag.

Comment: The purpose of the span is to achieve a CSS-effect which needs an element inside the <a>-tag.

Comment: Ah, you're probably using a css-sprite, right?

Comment: Nope, check out my demo here http://codepen.io/sebastianekstrom/pen/ezvEC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery and wrapInner() works also:

```
<p>Some text with <a class="generate_span" href="#">a link in it</a></p>

<script>
$('.generate_span').each(function(){
    $(this).wrapInner('<span data-title="'+($(this).attr('href'))+'"></span>');
});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/242b8/

Comment: This worked great, with a slight modification from `($(this).attr('href'))` to `($(this).text())`

Comment: Ok great. I thought you wanted href value in there.

Answer (score 6):

With PHP, you should be able to do it like that:

```
function wrap_anchor_text_with_span( $content ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && preg_match( '~<a(.*?)>(.*?)</a>~', $content ) ) {
        $content = preg_replace_callback( '~<a(.*?)>(.*?)</a>~', '_add_span', $content );
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'wrap_anchor_text_with_span', 10);

function _add_span( $matches ) {
    if ( ! ( $title = strip_tags( $matches[2] ) ) ) { // If we only have an image inside the anchor
        return '<a' . $matches[1] . '>' . $matches[2] . '</a>';
    } else {
        return '<a' . $matches[1] . '><span data-title="' . esc_attr( $title ) . '">' . $matches[2] . '</span></a>';
    }
}
```

What this function does is that it hooks to `the_content` filter and places a span inside all anchor tags.

**Note** that if the anchor contains an image, a span won't be added - if you want, you can change this behaviour by changing the `_add_span` function to:

```
function _add_span( $matches ) {
    return '<a' . $matches[1] . '><span data-title="' . esc_attr( strip_tags( $matches[2] ) ) . '">' . $matches[2] . '</span></a>';
}
```

A jQuery solution won't be really difficult either, but I think that the PHP only is sufficient enough.

Comment: I like this filter setup, I'm going to dig a bit deeper into that feature.

Comment: It's really useful - that's one of the great things about WordPress - the [Action Hooks and Filters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API#Hooks.2C_Actions_and_Filters). It makes it really easy to extend/override core functionality without messing with the core files.