# How to add HTML Tag and class inside Link Tag in Post - Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'd like to add classes and an html tag inside a link tag of Post so I linked a word to one of my wordpress page which look like this :

```html
<a href="http://localhost/website/contact/">contact</a>
```

and I want when I link it to be like :

```html
<a href="http://localhost/website/contact/" class="class1 class2"><span>contact</span></a>
```

because my theme use `span` to do a hover feature.

if possible only in Post (Blog part), there is a class which all posts has it's : `post-contents`

I know I can modify in the HTML Code of my post but I want it to be universal so as soon as I add a link in a post (even a new one) class and span tag are added

Any thought?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick;

```
function wrap_anchor_text_with_span( $content ) {
        if ( ! is_admin() && preg_match( '~<a(.*?)>(.*?)</a>~', $content ) ) {
            $content = preg_replace_callback( '~<a(.*?)>(.*?)</a>~', '_add_span', $content );
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'wrap_anchor_text_with_span', 10);

function _add_span( $matches ) {
    if ( ! ( $title = strip_tags( $matches[2] ) ) ) { // If we only have an image inside the anchor
        return '<a' . $matches[1] . '>' . $matches[2] . '</a>';
    } else {
        return '<a' . $matches[1] . '><span data-title="' . esc_attr( $title ) . '">' . $matches[2] . '</span></a>';
    }
}
```

> What this function does is that it hooks to [the_content](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) filter and places a span inside all anchor tags.

Note that if the anchor contains an image, a span won't be added. As per another answer from another thread, [Nikola Ivanov Nikolov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13702470/wordpress-add-a-span-tag-to-all-links)

Then use a filter to handle the anchors...

```
add_filter('the_content', 'addClassToLinks');
function addClassToLinks($content){
    return str_replace( '<a ', "<a class='myclass'", $content);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Regards,
-B.